# Growing data.frame in R, "The R Inferno Example"

Tags: r, dataframe

I copy paste an example from "[The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)" page 13 but it's not working.

It's about growing a data.frame in a more efficient way. Here is the code:

```
inferno <- function(n) {
    current.N <- 10 * n
    my.df <- data.frame(a=character(current.N),
                        b=numeric(current.N))
    count <- 0
    for(i in 1:n) {
            this.N <- rpois(1, 10)
            if(count + this.N > current.N) {
                    old.df <- my.df
                    current.N <- round(1.5 * (current.N + this.N))
                    my.df <- data.frame(a=character(current.N),
                                        b=numeric(current.N))
                    my.df[1:count,] <- old.df[1:count, ]
            }
            my.df[count + 1:this.N,] <- data.frame(a=sample(letters,
                                                            this.N, replace=TRUE), b=runif(this.N))
            count <- count + this.N
    }
    my.df <- my.df[1:count,]

    my.df
}
```

I am getting: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("6", "1", "9", "4", "9",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

What's wrong?

Comment: You characters are are being converted to factors and the levels for a factor aren't automatically updated when you append new values. It might be easiest to turn off "stringsAsFactors" for the duration of your function. Add `oldopt<-options("stringsAsFactors"=FALSE); on.exit(options(oldopt))` to the beginning of your function. That will avoid the usual conversion.

Comment: ...I might consider this a mistake in the R Inferno that should be updated. I would probably have simply specified `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in both calls to `data.frame()`.

Comment: There are actually three calls, that's why i suggested changing the `option()` once rather than updating all the data.frame calls

Comment: Ok, someone ping Mr. Burns(:-) ) with this info.